# Issue with _ILP32 in unix machine with gcc 2.96

Tags: rhel, gcc

I am using Red Hat Linux release 9 Kernel 2.4.20-8 on an i686 with gcc version 2.96. I have code something like:

```
include "stdio.h"

.....
ifndef _ILP32
return fopen64 (fname, dhtype);
else
return fopen (fname, dhtype);
endif
```

but I am getting an error saying:

> `fopen64' undeclared (first use this function).

I hope my operating system is 32-bit, but it is not detecting `_ILP32` and is going to the line `return fopen64 (fname, dhtype);`, which it should not.

How can I make my compiler detect `_ILP32`?

Comment: Perhaps `#` chars are missing in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#define _ILP32
```

by hand. Same effect has adding `-D_ILP32` to the compiler command line.

Another possiblity is to change  everywhere

```
#ifndef _ILP32
```

to

```
#ifdef _ILP64
```

which is defined  by gcc on 64bit systems.

Comment: it would probably be better to use a define that is automatically defined by the compiler, rather than hardcoding these things; try `cpp -dM /dev/null` to get a list of all automatic defines

Comment: @umläute The problem is that gcc defines `_LP64` in 64bit systems, but not also `_LP32` on 32bit system like other compilers.

Comment: I am using 32 bit system and is _ILP32 not defined for 32 bit system?

Comment: @user234559 This depends on the compiler. It seems that gcc does not define it. Therefore, I suggest you to define it manually.